# Move files to a folder within the folder

Tags: linux

I want to move files and folders to a folder within the same folder.
The following model is an example

```
|-folderN
|-- folder1
|-- folder2
|-- file1
```

So the question asked is how can I move everything at once from folderN (/var/www) to folder2?
Moving every file manually takes too long and it is not feasible in to long run.

Tried with

```
mv -v folderN/* folder2
```

and

```
mv folderN/* folder2
```

Comment: Please explain what's wrong in what you're doing.

Comment: what is the error you get with `mv folder1/* folder2` ? Please update your post to include this information.

Comment: There is no error, but it is simply not feasible to take them one by one. which is what I would be doing if I did with mv folder1/* folder2.

Comment: Are you trying to move all of `folderN/*` to `folderN/folder2/`, or all of `folderN/folder1/*` to `folderN/folder2`, or something else? Your question is ambiguous.

Comment: folderN/* to folderN/folder2/, sorry, I edited the question to rectify. @Useless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way using `ls` and `grep -v`. The `-v` option inverts the matching so only non matching lines are listed.

```
mv `ls | grep -v folder2` folder2
```

Note that backticks are used and not single quotes in the command.

Comment: This worked, it gave the error mv: cannot move 'folder2 to a subdirectory of itself, `folder2/folder2` but moved everything inside the folder that was needed.

Comment: @Schneejäger Hmm, that's odd. The `grep -v folder2` should have excluded folder2 from trying to be moved and eliminated the warning.

Answer (score 2):

Move the second folder one step up, move the contents, then move the second folder back. Like so:

```
cd folder1
mv folder2 ..
mv * ../folder2/
mv ../folder2 .
```

Comment: I cannot move the main folder one up because it is in /var/ and I don't have sudo/root privileges. It would be /var/www but if I want to move it one up it would be /var.

Comment: Move it to some other place where you do have write access. It's best if it's on the same file system, if possible, since that will be a lot quicker.

Comment: I thought of that but I am not allowed access everywhere and have to make with what I've got, but it was solved.

Comment: Yes, I saw and upvoted the accepted solution. This is Unix - there's almost always more than one way to do a thing, and what way you choose must depend on the particular circumstances. I'm glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

**`find`** + **`mv`** solution:

```
find folderN/ -mindepth 1 ! -wholename '*/folder2' -exec mv "{}" "folderN/folder2" \;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reporting that you are unable to move the contents of one folder to another? Is this the sequence of events you have tried?

```
$ ls folderN
file1 file2 folder1 folder2
$mv folderN/* folder2
mv: cannot move 'folder2 to a subdirectory of itself, `folder2/folder2`
$ls folderN/folder2
file1 file2 folder1
```

`mv folderN/* folderN/folder2` should be the only command you need.